# I don’t understand what the writer said in the blue circle.

Tags: linear-algebra

I think the blue circle doesn’t make sense, why $A$ scales all vectors in the span$\{v, v’\}$, by
lambda contradicts $A$ maps delta to the interior of $Q$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A is an operator, and operates on the set of unit vectors $\delta$. I believe the symbol above Q denotes "interior", so this statement would read: "The image of A applied to $\delta$ is in the interior of Q."

Comment: @JoshBone Yes,but I don’t think there’s a contradiction .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v \neq v'$ are both eigenvalues for $\lambda$ then $A = \lambda id$ when restricted to the plane containing both $v$ and $v'$ : every nonzero vector of this plane is an eigenvalue for $\lambda$.
However, this plane intersects the unit sphere quadrant $\Delta$ in an arc, and this arc has endpoints $w,w'$ that are not in the interior of $Q$ : there is some $w$ in the span of $v$ and $v'$ such that $w \not \gt 0$.

But since $A > 0$ and $w \ge 0$, we get $Aw > 0$. $w$ is an eigenvector so $\lambda w = Aw > 0$. And since $\lambda > 0$, we get $w > 0$ which contradicts our pick of $w$ at the end of the arc.